# can't back to the menu page in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

hi i am beginner in flutter and i'd like to know how to back to the menu apps page when clicking on a button.
I tried this method but it goes back to the previous page only
`onPressed: () { Navigator.of(context).pop(); }`

Comment: Hello, what do you mean by "menu apps page" ?

Comment: The list of apps in your phone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to quit your app.
This behaviour isn't recommended at all in the mobile's world, but if you really have to do it for a valid reason, you can use

`SystemNavigator.pop()` on Android
`exit(0)`  on iOS (but you may have your app removed from the Apple Store because of it)

You could also consider using the package [minimize_app](https://pub.dev/packages/minimize_app)

Answer (score 1):

Navigator pop only goes down one step by the tree , you can try to go spesific page you want with

```
onPressed: (() {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                      return SPESİFİC_WİDGET_HERE ;
                    }),
                  );

                }),
```

Read about navigation [Here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation)!